# Using Azure SQL AccessToken authentication with Microsoft.Azure.SqlDatabase.ElasticScale.ShardManagement

Tags: azure-sql-database, jwt, azure-elastic-sharding

I do not see where I can change the login method to use AccessToken when doing OpenConnectionForKey().  Also, I cannot change the login method after specifying creds to use tokens in SqlConnection.

Comment: Try these resources: https://github.com/Azure/elastic-db-tools/blob/master/Src/ElasticScale.Client/ShardManagement/Errors.Designer.cs

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/elastic-db-tools

Comment: That is the library I am using, and it doesn't handle Access token because it us using .net 4.5.  accesstoken became avail in 4.6.  So, I have been trying to mod this library.. @AlbertoMorillo

Comment: Could you please describe all your needs in detail and send them to my email alberto_morillo [AT] hotmail.com?. I will forward that to Microsoft Engineers and hopefully have a feedback. Please notify me here that you sent me the email, in case it goes to the junk folder on Outlook.

Comment: Dont see how email makes a diff.  I already posted a issue https://github.com/Azure/elastic-db-tools/issues/161

There is not much to describe beyond what is already stated.
the library doesnt support AccessToken auuthentication, because it is outdated.  It uses .net 4.51
@AlbertoMorillo

Comment: Not a problem, I just wanted to send your mail with your email in case SQL Azure team wanted  to contact you. A quick check on Internet will tell you I am a Microsoft Data Platform MVP and I just spend some of my time helping people. Hope you have a fast response via GitHub. Have a great day and thank you for your time!